# What is possible with event.PreventDefault() and ajax POST method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

**Problem?**

I have a problem where i can't use a normal HTML POST as it refreshes my webpage causing a JS controlled 'Tab' to close. Thus forcing the user to reopen the tab to see the feedback from the submitted form.

**How it should work**

The user enters their data into the form and then clicks submit, the form POSTs the data to itself, emailing the data to an email address. once the data is sent a message should replace the form saying the email had been sent. (all without the tab that contains the form  closing)

Sudo Code

```
If (email) is complete
    {Send Email} 

echo "thank you for for your email"

}else{

Display email form
```

**Solution i am trying?**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>

$('#form1').submit(function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'indextest2.php',
     data: $("#form1").serialize(),
     success: function(response) {

     }
   });
});
</script>
```

*Now this would be great as it stops the page refreshing and it sends the email but it stops the "thank you you message has been sent" html from replacing the form.*

So for all intents and purposes the user doesn't know if the email has been sent as the form is still there displaying the data they inputted.

**Possible workaround?**

Somehow getting the ajax post to insert the "thank you" message into the correct div on success of ajax post?! Is this possible?

Or am i doing something wrong, implementation wise?!

**Actual Code I'm using**

```
 <div id="tabsContainer">
    <div class='tab one'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#contact-form">Inquiry Form</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='content one'>
      <div id="contact-form" class="clearfix">
        <?php

  if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
$ToEmail = 'dancundy@hotmail.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'EasyScrap Enquiry'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["FName"]."&nbsp;";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= $_POST["SName"]."<br>";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Tel: ".$_POST["CTNumber"];
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "<br>"."email: ".$_POST["email"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "<br>"."Address: ".$_POST["STName"]." ".$_POST["PCode"];
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "<br>"."Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["Comment"]).""; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <P>Your message was sent, thank you! You will recieve an automated response within the next few minutes and will hear back from a Plymouth Easy Scrap representive shortly.</P>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php 
  }else{
      ?>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
    </legend>
    <div id="contact-area">
      <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
        <label for="FName">Name:*</label>
        <input name="FName" type="text" required placeholder="Enter your name" />
        <label for="SName">Surname:</label>
        <input name="SName" type="text" placeholder="Enter your surname" />
        <label for="STName">Street:</label>
        <input name="STName" type="text" placeholder="Enter the address" />
        <label for="PCode">PostCode:</label>
        <input name="PCode" type="text"placeholder="UK Postcode" />
        <label for="Email">Email:*</label>
        <input type="email" name="email"  required placeholder="Enter a valid email address"/>
        <label for="CTNumber">Contact:</label>
        <input name="CTNumber" type="text" placeholder="Enter a contact number"/>
        <label for="comment">Message:</label>
        <br/>
        <textarea name="Comment" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
      </form>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="FormInfo">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>*Denotes a required field</p>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <?php
  };
  ?>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>

$('#form1').submit(function(e)
{
event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'indextest2.php',
     data: $("#form1").serialize(),
     success: function(response) {

     }
   });
});
</script>
```

Here is the actual site which will give you a better idea what i mean when i say 'tab' and hopefully expand on the problem more.

http://www.cundytech.com/SWCF/indextest2.php

The tab with the form is "enquiry form" in the menu.

I really hope someone can help?

Comment: The ajax `success` callback is called when your post request completes. Use this callback to update the DOM and display your thank you message.

Comment: change `event.preventDefault();` to `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

once the messsage is sent , replace the form with the thank you message.
this could be done by replacing the dom structure containing the form with the thank you message within ajax success block

**ajax code:**

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e)
 {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'indextest2.php',
            data: $("#form1").serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                // replace the email form with thank you message
                $('#targetForm').html("<div class="info">Thank you for your message !!!<div>");
            }
      });
  });
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: the added code you suggested stops the ajax function from working altogether?

Comment: @DanCundy: then try escaping the quotes within div ,`$('#form1').html("<div class=\"info\">Thank you for your message !!!<div>");`

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you so much for your help really appreciate it. Finally i can move on to something else, been stuck on this for a couple weeks now. :)

Comment: Couple of weeks, thats a shocker. anyway your welcome, just one more thing, select this as answer, so that this question will be closed :)

Comment: I can only work on this project for maximum of two/three days a week as have a full time job that takes up most of my time. I usually only resort to using Stack if i am seriously stuck. Yep marked this answer, should be closed now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

The Solution posted by @deamweiver worked a treat. Using the Success part of the ajax post function i was able to swap out the form for a thank you message after successfully posting form data.

**This is the code needed**

```
('#form1').submit(function(e)
{
e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'indextest2.php',
     data: $("#form1").serialize(),
     success: function(response) {
 $('#form1').html("<div class=\"info\">Thank you for your message !!!<div>");
     }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what is **event** in your javascript?

In your argument you use **event** and in the function body you use **e**.

argument and variable must be same.

For your solution it should be **e**.

Following code may help you...

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e)
{
 e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'indextest2.php',
     data: $("#form1").serialize(),
     success: function(response) {

     }
   });
});
```

Comment: sorry i changed the E to Event yesterday when i was teaching myself how it worked, and forgot to change it back. As far as i'm aware it still works whether called e or event.

Comment: no if you use event it will throw an error because event is undefined in your scope. So, you have to use e and your page must not be reloaded.

Comment: @HasibHasanArnab: `e` or `event` is an argument. It works even if you call it `supercalifragilisticexpialidocious`

Comment: @Madara Uchiha please check the link http://jsfiddle.net/mhhtarnab/7uaRB/ and check in firebug that an error occured.

Comment: @HasibHasanArnab: You named your argument `e` but tried to use `event`... Please see this updated one. http://jsfiddle.net/7uaRB/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try following things:

indextest2.php page:

```
function index(){
    //Do whatever receiving the data
    if(Your job is done){
        echo "Success";
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }

}
```

ajax Call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form1').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'indextest2.php',
         data: $("#form1").serialize(),
         success: function(response) {
              if(response=="Success"){
                  $('#contact-area').html("<div>thank you you message has been sent</div>")
              }else{
                   $('#contact-area').html("<div>Sorry Something went Wrong !</div>")
              }
         },
         error: function (xhr) {
         alert(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
   });
});
```

The `e` you are using here is the event that generates after submitting the form or clicking the submit button. Then the browser refresh and goes to the `action=""` url that you have entered in `form` tag. Whenever you use `e.preventDefault` than it stops the `action` of form submission and does the code you write below of `e.preventDefault`. Generally people use `preventDefault` to stop refreshing browsers on `a` tag and `submit` buttons of `form`. Good Luck.

Comment: Thankyou for your detailed response @sujit. I will give this a try now.

Comment: Thank you for you answer @Sujit, however i found a solution that requires less editing of the code. And i am lazy! :) Thank you though.