# Send without reload page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi people I created one shoutboux, but I don't know how can I send the messages without reloading the page after submit..

**INDEX.PHP**

```
 /* TOP OF THE PAGE*/
<?php 

    //create the select query
    $STH = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM chat");

    $STH->execute();
?>
/* TOP OF THE PAGE*/

<div class="container">
        <div class="row all">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3>TEST Shoutbox</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div id="shouts" class="shouts">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul class="list-group">
                                <?php while ($row = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><span><?php echo $row['time'] ?> - </span><strong><?php echo $row['user'] ?>:</strong> <?php echo $row['message'] ?></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <?php if (isset($_GET['error'])) { ?>
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <?php echo $_GET['error'] ; ?>
                                </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <form action="process.php" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Enter A Message">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <input class="btn btn-primary shout-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Shout It Out">
                                </div>
                            </div>              
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

PROCESS.PHP

```
<?php 

    //check if form submitted
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $user = $_POST['user'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        //set timezone
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $time = date('H:i:s');

        if (!isset($user) || $user == '' || !isset($message) || $message == '') {

            $error = "Please fill in your name and a message";
            header('Location: index.php?error='.urlencode($error));
            exit();

        } else {

            $STH = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO chat (user, message, time) VALUES (:user, :message, :time)");

            $STH->bindValue(':user', $user);
            $STH->bindValue(':message', $message);
            $STH->bindValue(':time', $time);

            $STH->execute();

            header('location: index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }

?>
```

P.S: **I INCLUDED THE DATABASE DETAILS**

Some one can help me with this? How to send the messages without reload the page.. :(

**EDITED:**

I put this in **index.php** and I attributed id="submit" to submit button:

```
        <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#submit').click(function(){

$.post("process.php").serialize(),  function(response) {
$('#shouts').reload;
});
return false;

});

});
</script>
```

But didn't work..

Comment: Look up Ajax on *zee Weeb*

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Comment: I already searched but I don't know how to do, help me..

Comment: @thecreator We're not going to write it for you. This isn't a programming school. You have to learn it yourself, make an attempt, and if you can't get it working post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: I put what I tried.. I edited the question..

Comment: `didn't work` is not a useful description. What didn't work?

Comment: Continues reloading after I submit...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Ajax `Preventdefault()` funtion.

[event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

### Usage

```
$(".button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

A similar question I asked a while back.

[what-is-possible-with-event-preventdefault-and-ajax-post-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406285/what-is-possible-with-event-preventdefault-and-ajax-post-method)

Comment: It was an example. Not a tailored solution. You need to prevent the default action of the form when it is submitted. I had a similar problem i'll look to see if i can find the solution.

Comment: can u help me a little more? :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of letting your form POST the data, try sending it to your process script with an XHTTP request (commonly called AJAX).  jQuery can help [simplify this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).  Usually I will post the data via AJAX and have the script I am posting to return a [JSON-encoded](http://php.net/json_encode) response (indicating success / failure of the operation, any user-facing messages that should be displayed, etc).  You can also use AJAX to [poll for new messages](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) from your database periodically.  Of course there is much to consider but for the sake of experimentation and learning, this might help get you started.  Good luck!